# Javascript conditional regular expression if-then-else

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to limit the entries to a specific format.

If the entry has 5500 or 5100 such as 01\01-5500-000-00 then I want to have this:

```
^[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-$
```

But if the entry has anything other than 5500 or 5100 I want to have this:

```
^[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}$
```

How can this be accomplished with the if then else idea?

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: `^[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}-5[15]00-[0-9]{3}-$|^[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}-(?!5[15]00)[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}$`

Comment: I've used http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/regular-expression-tester.html to help me correctly create the expression. And I've tried using the pipe with 5500 in parenthesis like this: (?=.*5500)|^[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}$ - not correct

Comment: That tool only supports JS as I can see. But it is still possible.

Comment: By the way, `01\01-5500-000-00` does not match your first pattern. is it supposed to fail? Also, is the trailing `"-"` in the first pattern intentional?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Conditional regex syntax is not supported by JavaScript regex engine, but it can be worked around with a non-capturing group containing 2 alternatives:

1. One with the positive look-ahead and
2. The second with the reversed, negative look-ahead.

This regex meets your criteria and is JavaScript compatible:

```
^(?:(?=.*\b5[15]00\b)[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-|(?!.*\b5[15]00\b)[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2})$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oS6dR0/43)

Let me break it down:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?:`

  - `(?=.*\b5[15]00\b)[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-` - First alternative with the `(?=.*\b5[15]00\b)` look-ahead that requires a whole word `5500` or `5100` inside the string, and the first pattern you have
  - `|` - alternation operator
  - `(?!.*\b5[15]00\b)[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2})` - Second alternative that is prepended with the `(?!.*\b5[15]00\b)` negative look-ahead that makes sure there is no `5100` or `5500` inside the string, and only then matches your second pattern.
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

Use **conditionals**, Eg:

**(?(?=regex)then|else)**: `[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}\-(?(?=5[15]00)[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-|[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2})`

Regex conditionals example: [conditionals@regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yU6zU4/1)

In case that you're using a regex *engine* that is not PCRE based, you can be able to mimic the functionality by doing the following:

```
((?=positive-regex-statement)then|(?!negavite-regex-statement)then)
```

Eg.

```
^[0-9]{2,}\\[0-9]{2}\-((?=5[15]00)[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-|[0-9]{4}\-|(?!5[15]00)[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2})$
```

Mimic regex conditionals example: [mimic@regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dX1uI1/1)

Comment: @user974061: Could you please advise what is the programming language that you are using with this regular expressions? (The conditionals are supported only by PCRE like engines).

Comment: @Houseman: Did you actually read the whole post, or just down-voted for no reason? I provided an answer for non PCRE based engines (which also includes Javascript).

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, @Revo, I was a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this part of the pattern `[0-9]{4}` with the literal values for 5100/5500:

```
/^\d{2,}\\\d{2}-(?:5[15]00-\d{3}-|(?!5[15]00)\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{2})$/
```

- `[0-9]` is the same thing as `\d` in JavaScript
- For the else part, use the [negative lookahead](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!5[15]00)\d{4}` to guarantee it's not 5100/5500.