# JavaScript regular expression to match French licence plates

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a working version of PCRE regular expression that checks is a given string matches [French licence plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_France#SIV). It goes like this ([live demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fjG)):

```
/^(?(?!ss|ww)[a-hj-np-tv-z]{2})(?:\s|-)?[0-9]{3}(?:\s|-)?(?(?!ss)[a-hj-np-tv-z]{2})$/i
```

Now I would like to transform it to JavaScript regex syntax. I understand that [conditional regex syntax used here is not supported by JavaScript regex engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852857/javascript-conditional-regular-expression-if-then-else), so I should rewrite it.

I've started with a first group which:

1. Has to have two letters
2. They can't be SS nor WW
3. They can't use I, O, U

This is what I've come up with ([live demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ9aR6/1)):

```
/^(?!(?=(?:ss|ww))|(?![a-hj-np-tv-z]{2}))/i
```

And it works. Now I would like to add second part:

1. The first group can be (but doesn't have to be) followed by a white space character or a hyphen.
2. After that there is a group of exactly 3 digits.

So I've tried to add `(?:\s|-)?[0-9]{3}` and it fails. I guess it may have something to do with the fact that the very first group [is not consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804732/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-regex?lq=1), but I don't understand why. Optionally if anyone would also be able to help me with info on how to create a capturing group of the group of first two letters (I don't need it now, but hat would help me understand the process).

Comment: Don't forget that cars bought before 2009 may have always the old plate format (the one used since the 50's).

Comment: Yes, I will have them covered with this regular expression which works for both PCRE and JavaScript engines: `/^[0-9]{1,4}(?:\s|-)?[a-hj-np-tv-z]{2,3}(?:\s|-)?(?:97[1-6]|0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[1-5]|2[ab])$/i`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The begining can be

```
/^(?!ss|ww|.[iou]|[iou].)[a-z]{2}[-\s]?\d{3}/i
```

And the full expression is

```
/^(?!ss|ww|.[iou]|[iou].)[a-z]{2}[-\s]?\d{3}[-\s]?(?!ss|ww|.[iou]|[iou].)[a-z]{2}$/i
```

Comment: Can't find the flaw :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can simply use the following:

```
/^(?!ss|ww)[a-hj-np-tv-z]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?(?!ss)[a-hj-np-tv-z]{2}$/i
```

It seems to be working well for me.

Comment: Also a working answer. Yours was a bit later than Qwertiy's and I can't select both answers as the correct ones though :-/

Comment: @george007 This is more than fair. Thank you.