# JavaScript regex for YYYY-MM-DD with an optional month and day

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I came up with the following PCRE regex:

```
[12]\d{3}(-)?(?(1)(0[1-9]|1[0-2]))(-)?(?(3)(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))
```

It matches the following date formats:

- 2018-10-03
- 2011-03
- 2003

As you can see, I'm using conditional statements to detect whether there's a dash indicating a next part of the date. Unfortunately, javascript doesn't support conditional statements. How can I convert this to RegExp? I've tried using non-capturing groups containing alternatives, but I didn't manage to do it.

**EDIT:**

I can't use any JS functions because the regex will be used in the `pattern` HTML5 input property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18758772

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32852857

Comment: "it can be worked around with a non-capturing group"
"I've tried using non-capturing groups containing alternatives, but I didn't manage to do it."

I can't use jquery or any additional javascript functions, because this regex will be used in the `pattern` field (HTML5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[12]\d{3}(?:(?:-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))(?:-(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?)?
```

Basically it matches a year, then creates a non capturing Group with the `month` and the `date`. The `date` part is `optional` in this Group, and `the Whole Group` with month and date is also `optional`.

That Means it will match years alone, years and month alone and full dates with year, month and date.

**Edit** (added anchors):

```
^[12]\d{3}(?:(?:-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))(?:-(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?)?$
```

Now it won't match '2018-aaa'.

Comment: regex.test("2018-asd") --> true

Comment: The second one (after edit) works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is non-regex version I felt like making

```js
var dates = ["2018-10-03","2011-03","2003","12234"]

function isDate(str) {
  var parts = str.split("-"), 
      d = new Date(parts[0],parts.length>1?parts[1]-1:0,parts.length==3?parts[2]:1,12,0,0,0),
      yearOk=parts[0] < 3000 && d.getFullYear()==parts[0]; // or whatever test
  if (parts.length==1) return yearOk;
  var monthOk = +parts[1] == d.getMonth()+1;
  if (parts.length==2) return yearOk && monthOk;
  return yearOk && monthOk &&  +parts[2] == d.getDate();
}
dates.forEach(function(dStr) { console.log(isDate(dStr)) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex for `YYYY-MM-DD` pattern with optional month and day

```
var regex = /((([12]\d{3})(-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]))*)(-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))*)/;
```

Comment: regex.test("2018-asd") --> true