# ECMA Script check if group is defined

Tags: regex, c++11

I am trying to rewrite some Python expression to C++ with usage of `std::regex` with `ECMASynax`.

Here is the original expression:

`(?P<lower_bound>(?P<lower_bound_prefix>>|>=)?(?P<lower_version>([0-9a-zA-Z_]+(?:[.-][0-9a-zA-Z_]+)*))?(?(lower_bound_prefix)|\+))$`

I replaced all name capture groups to unnamed groups. Unfortunately, I can't make the last condition to happen. How can I represent this Python `re` syntax: `?(lower_bound_prefix)` in ECMASynax? I know I can reference groups using `\int` syntax, but how can I check if group has been defined?

Thanks

Comment: is this what you currently have? `((>|>=)?(([0-9a-zA-Z_]+(?:[.-][0-9a-zA-Z_]+)*))?(?(\1)|\+))$` ?

Comment: This feature does not work in ECMAScript even if the conditional construct were supported: all groups that have not participated in the match are initialized with an empty string, they are never `null`. You should re-consider the pattern logic.

Comment: Please add some test cases to help you re-vamp the pattern. Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/HU9JJ7/1) correct demo?

Comment: Thanks guys the comments. It seems like @David542 provided an answer that I followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this answer is better stated in a comment, but Javasript does not support conditional regex syntax.

Here is a good answer with an example: [Javascript conditional regular expression if-then-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852857/javascript-conditional-regular-expression-if-then-else) (first answer). If you want to post the current regex you have in your javascript/C++ I can help you convert it to use the non-conditional syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes that link answers my question, seems like I need to rewrite the expression with usage of conditionals `(?(?=regex)then|else)`